# The getCurrentUrl() method for IE WebDriver in Selenium only returning localhost

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

It only returns the local host address. I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction? The URL address it returns with the code below is as follows:
current url http://localhost:14423/

The code I am using is......

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class IEBrowserProblem {
    public static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Set up Ie driver
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\IeDriverFolder/IEDriverServer_x64_2.53.0/IEDriverServer.exe" );
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

        driver.get("http://localhost:4295/"); // I only included this in an attempt to overcome the issue
        driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.co.uk");

        String url4 = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        System.out.println("current url " + url4);

         driver.close();  

    }//main

}//class
```

Comment: Thank you Sanjay, The solution can be found from this youtube video. It was caused by IE settings! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GxTHU_91Z1Q

Answer (score 0):

Answer to be found at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GxTHU_91Z1Q

It is connected to IE settings which you need to configure manually.